# Python: How do I redirect output of os.system to python shell?

Tags: python

I want to make a simple batch script using python using os.system. I am able to run the commands just fine, but the output for those commands dont print to the python shell. Is there some way to redirect the output to the python shell?

Comment: Could you show some code? It's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: You could try using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead of `os.system`, it has better functionality (like redirecting output)

Comment: Yea, lots of people have suggested this, but I cant seem to get it to work. Do you know of a good step by step example of this? I am very new to Python and most of the examples I have found assume that you know what you're doing.

Comment: By 'the Python shell', do you mean IDLE? If you run it in a terminal, I think it should work.

Comment: @ThomasK You are totally right. Even using os.system(), if I run python from the terminal it prints properly. Put that into an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer as requested):

`os.system()` will work when run in a terminal - that's where stdout is going, and any processes you start will inherit that stdout unless you redirect it.

If you need to redirect into IDLE, use @root45's answer above (upvoted). That will work for most programs, but at least on Unixy systems, processes can also directly access the terminal they're run in (e.g. to request a password) - Windows may have something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I was testing my program in IDLE which is why I was having trouble, but the program was meant to run in the unix shell anyways. As soon as I ran it in the shell I saw the output just fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(['ls'], stdout=PIPE)
print p1.communicate()[0]
```

This will print the directory listing for the current directory. The `communicate()` method returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`. If you don't include `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` in the `Popen` call, you'll just get `None` back. (So in the above, `p1.communicate[1]` is `None`.)

In one line,

```
print Popen([command], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

prints the output of `command` to the console.

You should read more [here.](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote) There's lots more you can do with `Popen` and `PIPE`.